# Asynchronous crawler doesn't work properly [python]

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, web-crawler

I was trying to create asynchronous crawler and synchronous crawler and now I am facing one problem, the results of crawling are different but they supposed to be equal (results of crawling are the same if only depth is 1).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import networkx as nx
import urllib
import urllib.request
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import time
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from contextlib import closing


class Crawler:

 def __init__(self, delay, depth):
    self.delay = delay
    self.graph = nx.DiGraph()
    self.list_of_links = list()
    self.crawled_urls = list()
    self.depth = depth

 def validate_url(self, url):
    """Check if url is valid"""
    return 'http' in urlparse(url).scheme

 def run(self, async, start_list):
    if async:
        t1 = time.time()
        self.async_crawl(start_list, self.depth)
        t2 = time.time()
        print('Async seconds passed: ', t2 - t1)

    else:
        t1 = time.time()
        for elem in start_list:
            self.crawl(elem, self.depth)
        t2 = time.time()
        print('Sync seconds passed: ', t2 - t1)
    print('Links crawled: ', len(self.crawled_urls))
    print('Edges stored: ', len(self.list_of_links))
    print('Depth: ', self.depth)

 def crawl(self, url, depth):
    if url in self.crawled_urls:
        return []
    if depth and self.validate_url(url):
        self.crawled_urls.append(url)
        links = self.get_links(url)
        for link in links:
            self.list_of_links.append((url, link))
            self.crawl(link, depth - 1)
    else:
        return []

 async def fetch_page(self, session, url):
    """Get one page."""
    if url in self.crawled_urls:
        return []
    else:
        self.crawled_urls.append(url)
    try:
        with aiohttp.Timeout(10):
            async with session.get(url) as response:
                assert response.status == 200
                new_urls = self.parse_for_links(url, await response.text())
                for new_url in new_urls:
                    self.list_of_links.append((url, new_url))
                return new_urls
    except:
        return []

 def async_crawl(self, urls, depth):
    """Get multiple pages."""
    if depth:
        with closing(asyncio.get_event_loop()) as loop:
            with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop) as session:
                tasks = [self.fetch_page(session, url) for url in urls if self.validate_url(url)]
                new_urls = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
                if new_urls:
                    self.async_crawl(new_urls[0], depth - 1)


 def parse_for_links(self, url, text):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")
    return [urljoin(url, tag['href']) for tag in soup.findAll('a', href=True)]

 def get_links(self, url):
    try:
        req = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        req = map(lambda x: x.decode('utf-8'), req)
        return self.parse_for_links(url, ''.join(list(req)))
    except:
        return []

 def reset(self):
    self.list_of_links = list()
    self.crawled_urls = list()
    self.graph = nx.DiGraph()

 def visualize(self):
    self.graph.add_edges_from(self.list_of_links)
    nx.write_gexf(self.graph, "graph.gexf")

test2 = ['http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/']
cr = Crawler(10, 2)
cr.run(True, test2)
cr.reset()
cr.run(False, test2)
```

As for example I will show you one of my test cases:

```
Async seconds passed:  13.632593870162964
Links crawled:  371
Edges stored:  15374
Depth:  2
Sync seconds passed:  385.6858592033386
Links crawled:  371
Edges stored:  102755
Depth:  2
```

Comment: You never wait for `self.async_crawl()` to finish in your recursive definition of `async_crawl`. Also, your recursive call will spawn thousands of event loops, which probably isn't what you want to do. Implement this function instead with a queue and some sort of mutex to limit the concurrency.

Comment: @Blender can you tell me where can i find some articles about queue?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe best way use producers and consumers for async work.

```
    import asyncio
    import aiohttp

    from redd import redis.db.data   #just module for take data

    query = asyncio.Queue()
    locker = []

    async def producer(num):
        baseurl = redis.db.data
        while True:
            try:
                url = next(baseurl)
            except StopIteration:
                print('Producer {} end'.format(num))
                break
            else:
                await query.put(url)

    async def consumer(num):
        flag = True

        while flag:
            url = await query.get()
            async with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop) as session:
                async with session.get(url) as response:
                        result = await response.read()
                        print(result)
            if query.empty() and locker[num] is not True:
                locker[num] = True
                print('Thread number {} is END: {}'.format(num, locker[num]))
            if False not in locker:
                for task in asyncio.Task.all_tasks():
                    task.cancel()
                loop.stop()

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    for i in range(2):
        loop.create_task(producer(i))

    for i in range(5):
        locker.append(False)
        loop.create_task(consumer(i))

    loop.run_forever()
```